# Какую графическую библиотеку использовать для отображения графа?

Tags: c++, gui, графы

**Задание** - продемонстрировать обход неориентированного графа в ширину. Код обхода графа написать/найти не проблема. Но встал вопрос демонстрации графа. Конечно, можно вывести его списком смежности, но мне все же интересно, как можно нарисовать его? Знаю, что есть такая штука как Qt. Что еще можно использовать для этой задачи? Если подкинете идей или статей по этому поводу - будет круто (Англоязычные ресурсы приветствуются).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В книге *Бьерна Страуструпа "Принципы и практика использования C++"* во второй части (главы 12 - 16) рассматривается графический пользовательский интерфейс и программирование графики при помощи библиотеки FLTK (Fast Light Tool Kit). Там все очень доходчиво объясняется, много упражнений. В частности, для Вашей задачи подойдет класс `OpenPolyline`, описанный в этой книге. И кнопка `next` для обновления ;)

   - [Ссылка](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1949-6.html) на книгу Страуструпа, ее можно найти и скачать в формате
     pdf в интернете.
   - [Ссылка](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) на ресурс Страуструпа, на котором можно скачать примеры
     кода из книги.
   - [Ссылка](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) на сайт библиотеки FLTK. Как ее установить - описано в
     приложении книги.
2. Если хотите использовать более продвинутое средство, то рекомендую обратить внимание на библиотеку SFML (Simple and Fast Multimedia Library). Под нее имеется много описания непосредственно на сайте.

   - [Сслыка](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) на сайт библиотеки SFML.
   - [Ссылка](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/) на описание библиотеки. Все на английском, как и заказывали ;)

Answer (score 1):

GrapfViz очень удобен для таких целей.

https://www.graphviz.org/